# пишу бота для майна при запуске выдает ошибки

Tags: python, minecraft

```
from javascript import require, On
from time import sleep

minefalyer = require('minefalyer')


bot = minefalyer.createBot({
    'host' : 'localhost',
    'port' : '32980',
    'username' : 'fisher',
    'version' : '1.19.4'
})


@On(bot, 'spawn')
def spawn(*args):
    bot.chat(bot.username)
```

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\visual studio project\mine bot\lib\site-packages\javascript\connection.py", line 137, in com_io
    raise e
  File "D:\visual studio project\mine bot\lib\site-packages\javascript\connection.py", line 125, in com_io
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\visual studio project\знерщт3\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from javascript import require, On
  File "D:\visual studio project\mine bot\lib\site-packages\javascript\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    init()
  File "D:\visual studio project\mine bot\lib\site-packages\javascript\__init__.py", line 16, in init
    if config.global_jsi.needsNodePatches():
  File "D:\visual studio project\mine bot\lib\site-packages\javascript\proxy.py", line 225, in __getattr__
    methodType, val = self._exe.getProp(self._pffid, attr)
  File "D:\visual studio project\mine bot\lib\site-packages\javascript\proxy.py", line 145, in getProp
    resp = self.ipc("get", ffid, method)
  File "D:\visual studio project\mine bot\lib\site-packages\javascript\proxy.py", line 38, in ipc
    raise Exception(f"Timed out accessing '{attr}'")
Exception: Timed out accessing 'needsNodePatches'
```

Comment: У вас установлен Nodejs?

Comment: Советую впредь не использовать в путях русские буквы и пробелы, можно потом очень долго думать, в чем проблема:)

Comment: через visual studio, да

Comment: @pirozhok советую использовать vscode или pycharm. С python намного удобнее работать в этих IDE.

Comment: @ilya код написан в pycharm, еще устанавливал nodejs через pip install javascript

Comment: @pirozhok Вы устанавливали только pip install javascript или nodejs [от сюда](https://nodejs.org/ru) тоже

Comment: @gord1402 попробовал по вашему совету, теперь другие ошибки. сможете ли вы помочь мне по звонку в дискорде?

Comment: @pirozhok Лучше создайте новый вопрос или обновите этот. Это поможет другим людям с похожей проблемой при поиске её решения.